# mysql run a set of *.sql files from inside another sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a number of .SQL scripts, which consist of INSERT statements.

```
 INSERT INTO country (countryID, country_code, country_name) VALUES (5, 'AI', 'ANGUILLA');
 INSERT INTO country (countryID, country_code, country_name) VALUES (6, 'AL', 'ALBANIA');
```

I want to run them all from inside another script. I normally run them individually from the cmd line using SOURCE. How can I do this inside my .SQL script?

I'd like to run them using something like

```
 source 1.sql
 source 2.sql 
 source 3.sql etc.
```

Thanks